# Trying to create a edit in place style form in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This is my first attempt to create anything with vue.

[Here's a quick JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4wabpm6L/)

I'm trying to create a form that display the values without input, and then clicked, the input will display. I've managed to have a mockup "working", but I'm not very sure if this is the correct approach or not. I'm not very sure about:

```
Vue.nextTick(function() {
  document.getElementById(field.id).focus();
});
```

On the other hand, is there a recommended input validation library or something?

I would really appreciate any guidelines here :wink:

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding you first question I don't think there is an issue with using plain javascript to focus on your input. You can also achieve this with vue `refs`
See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13nb5b6t/4/)

This doesn't look cleaner but with refs you can put what you want as a ref and you are not limited by ids and in the end it's your choice what to use.

Regarding validation libraries here are a few:

1. [Vuelidate](https://github.com/monterail/vuelidate)
2. [Vee Validate](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate)
3. [Other ones](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#validation)

Comment: Yeah, i was more concerned about the Vue.nextTick than the way I was supposed to query the input. Thanks

Comment: nextTick is totally valid here since you are doing an action (focus) which needs the updated data (field.edit). It's not even possible without nextTick in this case

Comment: thanks for your replies. I really appreciate them ;)